# Can we use two identical deep neural networks with function cost at the middle

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, autoencoder

Assume I have input data x_1  as shown in the below figure,  which is the input of deep neural network (1), then the output is y_1.  The input of the deep neural network (2) is y_1 and its output should be similar to x_1  (In other words, it's similar to auto-encoder)

[image]

My question, is it possible to add a function cost for y_1, for example we need a cost function of the sum of (y_1)_{1:4:end} = 0 or minimum ?

Is it possible to implement that structure of deep neural network?

Comment: As long as you have the ground truth value to calculate the loss against, I don't see why not?

Comment: Yes, but how do we build the two deep neural network? I mean how we can cascade them together?  @Seankala

Comment: You just have to design them so that the second neural network's input is the output of the first. You could combine two loss functions, one for each neural network in this case.

Comment: You mean the first cost function will be for example (x_1 - x'_1).^2   and the second cost function would be (y_1)_{1:4:end} = 0 , and then combine the two cost functions, right ? @Seankala

Comment: Yes, that would be one possibility. The scenarios are endless and you should find the one that best fits your situation.